# How to play video when it appears in middle of the window?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement `Instagram`, `Facebook`, `9GAG` and etc's system of videos autoplaying when any specific video appears in the middle of the window/screen as the window/screen is being scrolled. So I want to create a system where there are numerous `video` on the page and when any specific `video` appears in the middle of the window/screen it should set `src` and start playing the `video` and remove `src` of the previous `video` playing. I have created my own logic, but it only works when the window is being scrolled **slowly**. It loses record of current video playing if the window is scrolled fast. So my logic is not good and efficient enough. Please help me build a better logic to playing `video` when they appear in the middle of the window.

`index.html:`

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    this.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

var content = document.getElementById("content"),
    video_player = undefined,
    current = 0;

for (var x=0;x<50;x++) {
    var video = document.createElement("video");
    video.controls = false;
    video.loop = true;
    video.autoplay = true;
    video.poster = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg/220px-Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg";
    content.appendChild(video);
}

function scroll_function () {
    if (this.oldScroll > this.scrollY) {
        if (current >= 1) {
            var previous_player = content.children[current-1];
            if ((this.scrollY + this.innerHeight/2) < previous_player.offsetTop + previous_player.clientHeight) {
                video_player.removeAttribute("src");
                video_player.controls = false;
                video_player.load();
                current--;
                video_player = content.children[current];
                video_player.src = "https://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb/bbb_640x360_60fps_1200k.mp4";
                video_player.controls = true;
                video_player.load();
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (current < 49) {
            var next_player = content.children[current+1];
            if ((this.scrollY + this.innerHeight/2) > next_player.offsetTop) {
                video_player.removeAttribute("src");
                video_player.controls = false;
                video_player.load();
                current++;
                video_player = content.children[current];
                video_player.src = "https://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb/bbb_640x360_60fps_1200k.mp4";
                video_player.controls = true;
                video_player.load();
            }
        }
    }
    this.oldScroll = this.scrollY;
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", scroll_function);

video_player = content.children[current];
video_player.src = "https://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb/bbb_640x360_60fps_1200k.mp4";
video_player.controls = true;
video_player.load();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 12.5%;
}
video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: Please note that video/audio playing is prohibited in modern mobile browsers. It is a very bad user experience as well. Hope you can differentiate between app experience and web experience.

Comment: @Raptor I'm going to allow users to select whether they want video autoplaying or not.

Comment: @Raptor It’s not explicitly prohibited, just restricted. Usability rules have to be followed in order to allow programmatic autoplaying of videos—vendors have been quite outspoken about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have created a perfect version, can someone check for any problems which can occur.

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    this.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

var content = document.getElementById("content"),
    video_player = undefined,
    current = 0,
    timeout = undefined;

for (var x=0;x<50;x++) {
    var video = document.createElement("video");
    video.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    content.appendChild(video);
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    var $this = this;
    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        var content_margin_top = $this.innerHeight * 0.11;
        var middle_line = $this.scrollY + ($this.innerHeight/2);
        for (var y=0; y < content.querySelectorAll("video").length; y++) {
            var player = content.children[y];
            if ((player.offsetTop + content_margin_top) < middle_line && (player.offsetTop + player.clientHeight + content_margin_top) > middle_line) {
                if (video_player != player) {
                    video_player.poster = "";
                    video_player.load();
                    video_player = player;
                    video_player.poster = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg/220px-Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg";
                    video_player.load();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }, 100);
});

video_player = content.children[current];
video_player.poster = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg/220px-Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg";
video_player.load();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgb(108, 171, 247);
}
#content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 98%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11%;
    left: 1%;
}
video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nav"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

now you should just validate if the video is in the center of the screan and this should work

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    this.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

var content = document.getElementById("content"),
    video_player = undefined,
    current = 0;

for (var x=0;x<50;x++) {
    var video = document.createElement("video");
    video.controls = false;
    video.loop = true;
    video.autoplay = true;
    video.poster = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg/220px-Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg";
    content.appendChild(video);
}
var timeout;
var previous_player;
function scroll_function () {
    var $this = this;
    var previous_player = content.children[current];
    window.clearTimeout(timeout); // this is to clear all previews operation
    timeout = setTimeout(function() { // and now start a new operation
    console.clear()
    var video_height = 500;
    var totalVideos = 49;
//a proper way to calculate which video to play 
            current =Math.floor(( $this.scrollY / (totalVideos * video_height )) * totalVideos ); 
            console.log(current)
                  
                // now you should just validate if the video is in the center of the screan and theis should work
                video_player = content.children[current];
                if (video_player){
                // here you should clear all previews player
               // video_player.removeAttribute("src");
               // video_player.controls = false;
               // video_player.load();
               // video_player = content.children[current];
                video_player.src = "https://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb/bbb_640x360_60fps_1200k.mp4";
                video_player.controls = true;
                video_player.load();
}
    },100);

    this.oldScroll = this.scrollY
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", scroll_function);

video_player = content.children[current];
video_player.src = "https://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb/bbb_640x360_60fps_1200k.mp4";
video_player.controls = true;
video_player.load();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 12.5%;
}
video {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `setTimeout` is a good strategy, but it still only works when the page is being slowly scrolled.

Comment: i made some changes and this should now work even when you fast scroll down or upp

Comment: Toma  I have answered this question below, can you check to which code is more efficient, your's or mine.

Comment: yours is good. as i have not validate the center position in my code. but if you look at the perfomance then mine is better, you loop throw each videos each time the user scroll and that is bad and in your solution you can see the lags. if you take a look at my solution i simple calculate the position of the video based on the scrollY. But your work is still good.